# How to ssh to a running X instance remotely?

Tags: ssh, remote, x11, teamviewer

I have an X instance running on my server computer, and on occasion I connect to it remotely via TeamViewer. Once in a while TeamViewer crashes and I cannot restart it remotely. Is there a way to login to my running X instance through ssh, and restart TeamViewer remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An X program needs two pieces of information in order to connect to an X display.

- It needs the address of the display, which is typically `:0` when you're logged in locally or `:10`, `:11`, etc. when you're logged in remotely (but the number can change depending on how many X connections are active). The address of the display is normally indicated in the `DISPLAY` environment variable.
- It needs the password for the display. X display passwords are called *magic cookies*. Magic cookies are not specified directly: they are always stored in X authority files, which are a collection of records of the form “display `:42` has cookie `123456`”. The X authority file is normally indicated in the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable. If `$XAUTHORITY` is not set, programs use `~/.Xauthority`.

You're trying to act on the windows that are displayed on your desktop. If you're the only person using your desktop machine, it's very likely that the display name is `:0`. Finding the location of the X authority file is harder, because with gdm as set up under Debian squeeze or Ubuntu 10.04, it's in a file with a randomly generated name. (You had no problem before because earlier versions of gdm used the default setting, i.e. cookies stored in `~/.Xauthority`.)

If this is a one-shot, you can detect the values of `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` from a running process. This is awkward to automate. You have to figure out the PID of a process that's connected to the display you want to work on, then get the environment variables from `/proc/$pid/environ` (`eval export $(</proc/$pid/environ tr \\0 \\n | grep -E '^(DISPLAY|XAUTHORITY)=')`).

A long-term, automatic solution is to copy cookies when you log into your desktop X session. Add the following lines to `~/.profile` (or some other script that is read when you log in):

```
case $DISPLAY:$XAUTHORITY in
  :*:?*)
    # DISPLAY is set and points to a local display, and XAUTHORITY is
    # set, so merge the contents of `$XAUTHORITY` into ~/.Xauthority.
    XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority xauth merge "$XAUTHORITY";;
esac
```

Then you can run programs on your remote X display simply by setting `DISPLAY`:

```
ssh foo.example.com 'DISPLAY=:0 restart teamviewer'
```

*This answer is adapted from a [more complete answer to a similar question on Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/ssh-display-variable/10126#10126).*

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to remotely (via SSH) start a vncserver on the relevant display. After that use SSH tunneling to connect a vnc client from your remote machine through the SSH connection to the VNC server.

Comment: I actually have been trying that, but VNC is not as reliable as TeamViewer and also it is much slower. For some reason, every time I started using VNC for actual work, it ended up crashing and I ended up losing all my work.

Comment: Well, it should be enough to restart TeamViewer?

Comment: I tried that as well. For some reason running TeamViewer in VNC crashes VNC right away. I don't have enough knowledge in VNC, so I thought figuring that out would be a harder task.